# Как добавить пользователя в группу в Active Directory с помощью pl/sql?

Tags: plsql, active-directory

Для добавления пользователя в AD я использую пакет `dbms_ldap`, процедуру `dbms_ldap.add_s`.
Теперь мне нужно добавить пользователя в определенную группу.
Пытаюсь добавить атрибут memberOf:

```
dbms_ldap.populate_mod_array(
    l_modarray, 
    dbms_ldap.MOD_ADD, 
    'memberOf', 
    ldap_helper.to_strcol('CN='||GroupName||',OU=User Accounts,DC='host',DC=test'));
```

но выдается ошибка.
Пытался сделать `dbms_ldap.modify_s` самой группы, но тоже выдается ошибка.